# Changing a class variable with an if statement

Tags: android

Right now as my game is running I have obstacles on the screen I made.  Once the score reaches 7 I would like to change the picture the obstacles are.

```
 public GameplayScene(Context context){
        ...
        obstacleManager = new ObstacleManager(125, 400, 50, Color.LTGRAY, "clouds");
        obstacleManager1 = new ObstacleManager(125, 700, 50, Color.DKGRAY, "stormcloud");
        ...
}
```

I would like this to happen

```
if(score >= 7){
            obstacleManager.setPic("goodalien");
            obstacleManager1.setPic("badalien");
        }
```

Once the score reaches 7 the pictures don't change, anyone know why or how to fix it?

Comment: what is problem it shows in log ?

Comment: @Ashish it doesn't say anything